# S3 and heroku. not insecure scripts on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, heroku, amazon-s3

I have added my js scripts to s3 and css files. but whenever they try to load in chrome they appear [blocked] next to them. I have to then click a little shield in the upper right part of the screen to allow them to be used. Is there anything i can do that users on chrome do not have to do this (any settings in heroku/s3/ etc??) it seems like a huge pitfall of using heroku + s3 + chrome?

Comment: Are you running the site on https but linking to the resource files in S3 using http links?

Answer (score 1):

As @friism says, you're probably linking to the scripts via http, but visiting an https version of your site.

I've made this mistake several times with jQuery from a CDN,  you need to do:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js
```

instead of

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: I just ran into this exact issue and thought it was my `.js` file. It turns out I was sourcing my `jquery.js` via `http://`. Also, if you need hosting for your `.js` files, check out https://pages.github.com/. You can link a project page to a repository containing your `.js` files, then use the .io path to the file to source them in your app!